# Java / Spring: How to Instatiate an Object on Server Startup

Tags: java, spring

I am writing a web service using jax-rs and spring.  I have a Singleton class representing a database connection pool, called "Datasource".

```
     Datasource datasource = Datasource.getInstance();
     Connection connection = datasource.getConnection();
```

This code runs, and hence the singleton is created on the first "query", but I'd like to create the singleton instance on server startup.  How do I accomplish this?  In my web.xml, I have

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/application.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And in application.xml I have

```
 <bean name="myRoutes" class="com.package.myClass" />
```

Do I add a bean here?

Comment: The idea behind DI frameworks such as Spring is to *eliminate* singletons like `Datasource`. Is there a reason you are not injecting an instance everywhere, instead of manually calling `getInstance()`?

Comment: @TomG, probably only that I'm brand new to the framework and haven't grokked much of it yet.  What does that look like?

Comment: In your classes where you would use the `Datasource`, you would request that it is injected via `@Autowired` -- e.g. `@Autowired public Foo(Datasource ds) { ... }`. If you provide a single `Datasource` instance as a bean, by configuring it in XML, it will be provided to those classes when they are created. Check the Spring docs for more background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, ApplicationContext implementations eagerly create and configure all singleton beans as part of the initialization process. The singleton scope is the default scope in Spring.

When defining a bean that you create with a static factory method, you use the `class` attribute to specify the class containing the static factory method and an attribute named `factory-method` to specify the name of the factory method itself.

```
<bean
    id="dataSource"
    class="com.package.DataSource"
    factory-method="getInstance" />
```

Comment: For new projects, I highly recommend the new annotation-based syntax. In one of your `@Configuration` objects, you just have a method `@Bean public DataSource dataSource()` that returns the correctly-constructed object, and Spring will pick it up and make it available.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by this definition you create singleton spring bean on server startup:

```
<bean name="myRoutes" class="com.package.myClass" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to implement a `ServletContextLitener`, and define it as a listener in the deployment descriptor. As per the doc

The javadoc of  `ServletContextListener`'s `contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)`  method says

> Notification that the web application initialization process is
>   starting. All ServletContextListeners are notified of context
>   initialization before any filter or servlet in the web application is
>   initialized

[Mkyong's website takes the same example to demonstrate the use](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/what-is-listener-servletcontextlistener-example/)